# Efficiency of long sequences of reference members

Tags: c++, reference

Lets say I have some classes like these:

```
class A
{
public:
    int data;
};

class B
{
public:
    A& a;
    B(A& x) : a(x) {}
};

class C
{
public:
    B& b;
    C(B& x) : b(x) {}
};

A a;
B b(a);
C c(b);
```

If I need some class D which needs to be able to access all of the instances of the other classes, which definition of D would be better for run time and memory usage? Is there a trade-off here?

Possibility 1:

```
class D
{
public:
    C& c;
    D(C& x) : c(x) {}
};
D d(c);
```

Access the data of class A object like this:
`int x = d.c.b.a.data;`

Possibility 2:

```
class D
{
public:
    A& a;
    B& b;
    C& c;
    D(A& x, B& y, C& z) : a(x), b(y), c(z) {}
};
D d(a,b,c);
```

Access the data of class A object like this:
`int x = d.a.data;`

For my purposes, D2 will never be initialized with references that C does not also have access to.

Is one of these options always better than the other? Is it a time vs. space issue?

Comment: Off the top, `D2` is not equivalent to `D1`. The former can be constructed with references to instances unrelated to each other: in other words, it's possible that `&b.a != &a` and/or `&c.b != &b`. Come to think of it - why does `D2` need to store `B&` and `C&` at all? They don't add any utility.

Comment: Ah, I have added  a specifcation at the end. I thought it may be beneficial to store B& and C& so as not to go through a long string of members should I want to access them. Does going through these references have any meaningful time costs?

Comment: `B` and `C` don't have any members other than `A&`, which `D2` already has access to independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of space, it will be fairly close (unless you are allocating enormous numbers of objects). A reference is really just a pointer, so these classes aren't too big to begin with. With the second implementation of `D` you will get some duplication (you'll have two references to an `A`), but that seems like it would be negligible overall.

Time *could* become an issue. Using version 1 of `D` involves reading 5 memory locations to reach `a`'s `data` member. This can potentially cause cache misses and, worst case, page faults. It seems unlikely this is would be the case. It really depends on where the objects are allocated. Not only that, but it just involves more instructions to execute `d.c.b.a.data`. That isn't to say that version 2 is immune to the cache/paging problems, they just get a little less likely when you are referencing fewer variables. It's hard to make any concrete statements about how much time it will take with the information you provided. These are just some potential issues.

Unless you are working with large programs and large data in a high performance setting, these considerations are likely to be moot. Better software design would likely be the overriding factor in selecting a design.

Lastly, version 1 of `D` seems like a better OO design than version 2.

Comment: Thanks for the well-thought-out answer. I'll probably end up using D2, if only for the OO design.

Comment: @KaiSchmidt You're welcome. It's well worth the time to learn about the impacts of caching and paging. They can affect performance of your program dramatically.